# Update oracle table with start and end times from shell script

Tags: shell, ksh

There are three materialized views being refreshed in a single shell script(.ksh) and I am trying to insert the start, end timestamps for each MV in a oracle table(created for audit purpose). I tried creating a .sql file with insert statement that is being called at end of each refresh but unable to get the intended result. This is the first time I am working on shell script, can anyone please help me?

Thanks and Regards
Kiran.

**CODE:**

```
typeset -Z6 i
i=0
echo $PROP_FILE
VIEWS=$(echo $viewset| tr "," " ")
for VIEW in $VIEWS
do
    echo "Generating $XML_FILE" 
    echo " "
    echo "Start Refresh view: ${VIEW} at : $(date)"
    if [ $DB_READ_FLAG -eq 0 ]
    then    
        echo "calling launch_sqlplus.ksh "
        #YRV
        #Adding below line fix the defect 7494
        #$BIN/launch_sqlplus.ksh $SQL/exports_refresh_view.sql $VIEW \
        #$BIN/launch_sqlplus.ksh $SQL/exports_refresh_view.sql $VIEW || exit_with_error       
    else
        echo "calling launch_sqlplus_read."
        #YRV
        #Adding below line fix the defect 7494
        #$BIN/launch_sqlplus_read.ksh $SQL/exports_refresh_view.sql $VIEW \
        # $BIN/launch_sqlplus_read.ksh $SQL/exports_refresh_view.sql $VIEW || exit_with_error
    fi
    echo "End Refresh view: ${VIEW} at : $(date)\n"
```

**LOG FILE:**

> Start Refresh view: mv_lt_port_config at : Wed Aug 27 20:09:34 METDST
>   2014 calling launch_sqlplus_read.
>
> Loading /isii/isi/bin/isi_profile_read isii
>
> Launch SQL-script with paramaters :
>   /isii/isi/sql/exports_refresh_view.sql mv_lt_port_config
>
> Session altered.
>
> Session altered.
>
> Session altered.
>
> Session altered.
>
> old   1: ALTER SESSION SET tracefile_identifier=mv_refresh_&1 new   1:
>   ALTER SESSION SET tracefile_identifier=mv_refresh_mv_lt_port_config
>
> Session altered.
>
> Session altered.
>
> Session altered.
>
> old   2:      xml_report.refresh_mview('&1'); new   2:
>   xml_report.refresh_mview('mv_lt_port_config');
>
> PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
>
> End Refresh view: mv_lt_port_config at : Wed Aug 27 20:12:17 METDST
>   2014

Comment: You'll have to show your code.

Comment: Dear Glenn Jackman, Added the code for your reference. can you please check?

Comment: Hi, did you find a resolution to your issue? If so can you please update this question? Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

This answer may be partial, because of incomplete code in the question, however values can be inserted into a DB table from a ksh script as follows:

Assuming a DB Table is created -

```
CREATE TABLE VIEW_REFRESH_LOG
             (OPERATION VARCHAR2(60),
              START_DATE DATE,
              END_DATE DATE);
```

Then the following sql file can be created -

```
REM ----------- insertRecord.sql -------------------------------
DEFINE DATEFORMAT = 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'
DEFINE OPERATION = &1
DEFINE STARTING = '&2 &3'
DEFINE ENDING = '&4 &5'

INSERT INTO refresh_log 
           ( operation, 
            start_time, 
              end_time)
      VALUES 
           ('&OPERATION', 
           to_date('&STARTING','&DATEFORMAT'), 
           to_date('&ENDING','&DATEFORMAT'));

COMMIT;
EXIT SUCCESS;
```

then, in the shell script -

```
...
CREDENTIALS="oracle_user/oracle_pass"
echo "Start Refresh view: ${VIEW} at : $(date)"
    if [ $DB_READ_FLAG -eq 0 ]
    then    
        echo "calling launch_sqlplus.ksh "
        #YRV
        #Adding below line fix the defect 7494
        STARTDATE=$(date '+%d-%m-%Y')
        STARTTIME=$(date '+%H:%M:%S')
        #$BIN/launch_sqlplus.ksh $SQL/exports_refresh_view.sql $VIEW \
        $BIN/launch_sqlplus.ksh $SQL/exports_refresh_view.sql $VIEW || exit_with_error
        ENDDATE=$(date '+%d-%m-%Y')
        ENDTIME=$(date '+%H:%M:%S')
        PARAMETERS="'launch_sqlplus ${VIEW}' '${STARTDATE}' '${STARTTIME}' '${ENDDATE}' '${ENDTIME}'"
        sqlplus -S $CREDENTIALS @insertRecord.sql "$PARAMETERS"
    else
        echo "calling launch_sqlplus_read."
        #YRV
        #Adding below line fix the defect 7494
        STARTDATE=$(date '+%d-%m-%Y')
        STARTTIME=$(date '+%H:%M:%S')
        #$BIN/launch_sqlplus_read.ksh $SQL/exports_refresh_view.sql $VIEW \
        $BIN/launch_sqlplus_read.ksh $SQL/exports_refresh_view.sql $VIEW || exit_with_error
        ENDDATE=$(date '+%d-%m-%Y')
        ENDTIME=$(date '+%H:%M:%S')
        PARAMETERS="'launch_sqlplus_read ${VIEW}' '${STARTDATE}' '${STARTTIME}' '${ENDDATE}' '${ENDTIME}'"
        sqlplus -S $CREDENTIALS @insertRecord.sql "$PARAMETERS"
    fi
    echo "End Refresh view: ${VIEW} at : $(date)\n"
```

That would derive the start and end time of the operation you're performing, and pass it as parameters to SQL*Plus, which takes those parameters and inserts them as bind variables into the sql script.

You need to be wary of the quotes when passing strings as parameters to SQL*Plus. Also, you'd want to modify your DATEFORMAT to whatever your value is for NLS_DATE_FORMAT.

Hopefully that addresses your question. If not, please clarify further.